# Using a DTO and retrieving an ORM subresource using a uriVariable in API Platform/Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, dto, api-platform.com

I'm using API Platform 3 with Symfony 6 to build an API. I have an ORM entity Subscriber. To change certain fields of the Subscriber, I want to use PUT with a Data Transfer Object (DTO). Since I need the underlying Subscriber and want API platform to check whether this Subscriber exists (and return a 404 if it does not) and automatically retrieve it (for use in the StateProcessor), I am trying to pass the identifier of the Subscriber in the URL as a uriVariable (its called subscriberId in the URI but the actual identifier in Subscriber is simply id).

However, this always returns a 404, presumably because he attempts to retrieve a SaveSubscriberDetails DTO object with the subscriberId, which cannot work since it's not an ORM entity that is persisted anywhere. The API route exists. When I remove the uriVariable in the ApiResource configuration, I reach the state processor (checked by debugging). When I leave it in, I never reach the state processor. The Subscriber with the id I pass in the URL does exist.

My attempt:

```
#[ApiResource(
    uriTemplate: '/subscriber/{subscriberId}/saveDetails',
    operations: [
        new Put(input: SaveSubscriberDetails::class, processor: SaveSubscriberDetailsProcessor::class),
    ],
    uriVariables: [
        'subscriberId' => new Link(
            fromProperty: 'id',
            fromClass: Subscriber::class
        ),
    ],
    output: SaveSubscriberDetails::class
)]
```

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

- Am I just using the Link attribute in a wrong way?
- Do I need to add a private property subscriberId of type int or a property subscriber of type Subscriber to my SaveSubscriberDetails DTO to link to it?
- Do I maybe need to customize the deserialization process that results in the SaveSubscriberDetails object?
- Can/should I just pass the subscriberId uriVariable and tell him not to interpret it whatsoever and instead just retrieve the underlying Subscriber object from the database in the SaveSubscriberDetailsProcessor state processor?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass your uriTemplate / uriVariables / output under the operations key, like that (https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#configuring-operations) :

```
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Put(
            uriTemplate: '/subscriber/{subscriberId}/saveDetails',
            uriVariables: [
                'subscriberId' => new Link(
                    fromProperty: 'id',
                    fromClass: Subscriber::class
                ),
            ],
            input: SaveSubscriberDetails::class,
            output: SaveSubscriberDetails::class,
            processor: SaveSubscriberDetailsProcessor::class,
        ),
    ],
)]
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem. I removed the uriVariables parameter and use the repository in the state processor to retrieve the ORM entity instead.